# How to call lists in a for loop?

Tags: python-2.7

I am stuck at a failry simple looping exercise through lists and getting error "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable". 
I have three lists with n number of records. I want to write first record from all lists in the same line and want to repeat this procedure for n number of records, it will result in n number of lines. Following are lists that I want to use:

```
lst1 = ['1','2','4','5','3']
lst2 = ['3','4','3','4','3']
lst3 = ['0.52','0.91','0.18','0.42','0.21']

istring=""
lst=0
for i in range(0,10): # range is simply upper limit of number of records in lists
    entry = lst1(lst)
    istring = istring + entry.rjust(11) # first entry from each list will be cat here
    lst=lst+1
```

Any startup would be really helpful.

Comment: I think you just mean `lst1[lst]`

Comment: Create a list of lists and then loop over them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> lst1 = ['1','2','4','5','3']
>>> lst2 = ['3','4','3','4','3']
>>> lst3 = ['0.52','0.91','0.18','0.42','0.21']
>>> a = zip(lst1, lst2, lst3)
>>> istring = ""
>>> for entry in a:
...     istring += entry[0].rjust(11)
...     istring += entry[1].rjust(11)
...     istring += entry[2].rjust(11) + "\n"
... 
>>> print istring
          1          3       0.52
          2          4       0.91
          4          3       0.18
          5          4       0.42
          3          3       0.21
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I want except the only thing is that I don't know the number of records in the lists after each run of the earlier script. How to take care of that?

Comment: @Ibe Are you trying to print out the line number with each line? You can get the count for each iteration of the `for` loop by doing `for index,entry in iter(a):` where `index` will be the current loop count.

Comment: no, I don't want the count of lines except only want to automate "entry[0], entry[1]...." without writing [0], [1],... as I don't know the number of records after each run.

Comment: @Ibe The indexes [0], [1], [2] refer the number of lists, not the number of records in each list.

Answer (score 3):

This works for any size of lists:

```
for i in zip(lst1, lst2, lst3):
    for j in i:
        print j.rjust(11),
    print

          1           3        0.52
          2           4        0.91
          4           3        0.18
          5           4        0.42
          3           3        0.21
```

Comment: Very well. I tried to catch j.rjust(11) as a variable 'x' but printing that variable is not formatted as above. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Ibe, if you do `x = j.rjust(11)` followed by `print x,` is should work the same.  Make sure you have the comma in the right place.

Answer (score 1):

Try `entry = lst1[lst]` instead of `entry = lst1(lst)`

() usually denotes calling a function, whereas

[] usually denotes accessing an element of something.

A list is not a function.

Also, while you can keep your own index, a for loop makes this unnecessary

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,7,9,11,13,15]
y = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20]
z = [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
for i in range(0,10):
   print x[i], y[i], z[i]

1 2 3
2 4 4
3 6 5
4 8 6
5 10 7
7 12 8
9 14 9
11 16 10
13 18 11
15 20 12
```